# Displaying Inventory Count on Hand in Spree front-end on Product Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, e-commerce, spree, deface

I'm trying to simply display the inventory count (the number displayed in the spree admin as "count on hand") in the front-end of my app.  I'd like to display it on the product page to show how many of a product is left available...i'm still getting familiar with Spree...can I just do this through the front-end via deface changes???

I'm using Spree 2-1-stable...so far i've tried to replace the unordered list in the _taxons partial (spree / frontend / app / views / spree / products / _taxons.html.erb) with the count on hand using the following deface override...but i think I may be way off base.

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/products/_taxons',
  :replace => "ul#similar_items_by_taxon",
  :text => "<%= product.total_on_hand %>",
  :name => "product_profile_changes",)
```

(A previous stackO posting below had said to call total_on_hand, but that doesn't seem to be working either...)

[Show all spree ecommerce products together with their count-on-hand displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248395/show-all-spree-ecommerce-products-together-with-their-count-on-hand-displayed)

My current code throws the following error:

```
SystemStackError in Spree::ProductsController#show
stack level too deep

Rails.root: /Users/user/Documents/spree_flash_sales/spec/dummy
```

If i have to add something to the controller or model, which specific files would it go in and what would the code look like?  Any help would be much appreciated...thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i guess i'll leave my own answer...another boneheaded mistake.

I just left out the @ in the text line.  i.e,

:text => "<%= @product.total_on_hand %>",

(I need to take some courses on debugging)